# How to trigger a Jenkins pipeline A (In Kubernetes pod "x") from another Jenkins pipeline B (In Kubernetes pod "y")

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-pod

I have Jenkins pipeline "A" in Kubernetes pod "x", Jenkins pipeline "B" in Kubernetes pod "y" in same cluster. How to trigger Jenkins pipeline "A" from another Jenkins pipeline "B" here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what this means.  Are you saying you have two Jenkins Masters running in two different pods? Or one Jenkins Master that can run jobs in two pods

Comment: I have two jenkins masters running in two different pods.